# MSI to install MySql secretely

Tags: .net, mysql, windows-installer, database

we're developing a huge WPF client app.

this will have a lot of informations and data stored on a DB for statistic complex calculations, we planned to use sqlite, but it's definitely not suited for working with table like 150col * thousands of rows.

One "guy" told me we could use mysql and let the msi install mysql under the hood, as it's going to be used by noobs & normal users.

I've never seen a msi installing mysql, and definitely not under the hood, is that even possible? could be a solution for our issue.

Thanks,
Luca

Comment: So you have tested SQLite and you found that it was unsuitable to your needs or did you just decide that based on someones blog and experience? I have seen well developed SQLite databases with huge data outperform badly developed MySQL systems. Just keep in mind SQLite is a embedded database so it is suited for applications needing a local database. Installing a entire MySQL database to replace an embedded solution is overkill and going to cause a lot of maintenance work. The choice is yours but I would suggest you think about this a little more. Maybe try on SQLite..

Answer (score 0):

If SQLite doesn't give you what you need, how about MS SQL Compact Edition?

I agree with Luca that working with an embedded solution is probably the way forward in this instance. Your Db doesn't sound all that big anyway.

Comment: We are actually trying a postgresql, because of MS SQL CE limits, should be easier to install instead of MSSQL